# Error Custom TableViewCell : swift dynamic_cast class unconditional

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, dynamic-cast

I'm getting error as swift dynamic_cast class unconditional for the following,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      var   cell :CustomTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as CustomTableViewCell;    // error here

        return cell
    }
```

Please help me to solve this.
Thank You!

Comment: remove semicolon at last of your error line and try

Comment: That dint work! thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Below command to be added in viewDidLoad method,you should register with your custom cell class

```
 self.tableView.registerClass(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Answer (score 0):

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier()` is returning an optional of type `AnyObject`. So a force type casting ma cause problem. if you use `as?` for type casting will work i guess

```
  var   cell :CustomTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? CustomTableViewCell; 

   // cell will not be nil if you registered already. Bt this if check may be needed to supress the warning of optional use
    if let _cell = cell{

    }
```

Comment: Thanks! But, it shows error! asking to add '!' instead of '?' . tat doesnt work :-(

Comment: can you try like `var cell :CustomTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? CustomTableViewCell`

Answer (score 0):

In Latest **Xcode 15** or later we don't need to add register custome cell class in tableview. If you try adding on tableview custome cell class, you will getting the **unwrap optional error**.

```swift
self.tableView.register(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```